# Upload file from Angular JS to Sails JS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, file-upload, sails.js

I'm new with Sails and Im trying to upload a file using Angular in the frontend side. This is my FileController

```
module.exports = {
    upload: function  (req, res) {
        req.file('file').upload({
            dirname: require('path').resolve(sails.config.appPath, '/assets/images')
        },function (err, uploadedFiles) {
            if (err) return res.negotiate(err);

            return res.json({
                message: uploadedFiles.length + ' file(s) uploaded successfully!'
            });
        });

    }
};
```

and I'm getting this error trying to create a directory to save the file:

```
Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: 
 Error: EACCES, mkdir '/assets' { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/assets'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/assets' }
```

and if I delete that line with the dirname, I think its supposed to save it into a temp folder by default. I tried that, I got the success message, but no temp folder is created. any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.
You have to change this line:

```
dirname: require('path').resolve(sails.config.appPath, '/assets/images')
```

with this one:

```
dirname: sails.config.appPath + '/assets/images'
```

The problem was that you needed root permissions because Sails was creating a folder in you home directory (and not in your app folder...).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you got the right permisions to the folder that you want to upload the files, try sudo chmod 775 assets/

Comment: same problem, and if I delete that line I think its supposed to save the file in a temp folder by default, so I tried that, I got the success message, but there is no temp folder

Comment: Also make sure that the file that is running the server got the right permissions too.